# How to test Bluetooth Based Application on Androidx86 on top of VirtualBox with inbuilt laptop bluetooth

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, virtualbox, android-x86

How can I run Bluetooth Based application on Android emulator on my laptop. When I run the Bluetooth application, it's said, Bluetooth Device not connected. I was googled and I found a way for using `Oracle VM VirtualBox`. and I followed this steps too,

1. Download Androidx86 from http://www.android-x86.org/. This is an .iso file, so you'd need something like VMWare or VirtualBox to run it. Me, I use VirtualBox.
2. When creating the virtual machine, you need to set the type of guest OS as Linux instead of Other.
3. After creating the virtual machine, set the network adapter to 'Bridged'.
4. Start the VM and select 'Live CD VESA' at boot.
5. Now you need to find out the ip of this VM. Go to terminal in VM (use Alt+F1 & Alt+F7 to toggle) and use the netcfg command to find this.
6. Now you need open a command prompt and go to your android install folder (on host). This is usually C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>.
7. Type adb connect IP_ADDRESS
8. There done! Now you need to add Bluetooth. Plug in your USB Bluetooth dongle.
9. In VirtualBox screen, go to Devices>USB devices. Select your dongle.
10. Done! now your Android VM has Bluetooth. Try powering on Bluetooth and discovering/paring with other devices.
11. Now all that remains is to go to Eclipse, and run your program. The Android AVD manager should show the VM as a device on the list.

I did this and it's working fine. but the problem is, if I use Bluetooth Dongle it's working good, but I can't use my Laptop's inbuilt Bluetooth device with VM Machine. How can I connect my inbuilt Bluetooth device with VM Machine and how can I use it for Test Bluetooth Based Application.? Kindly suggest some ideas. thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Virtual Box :

1. right click and go to settings
2. select Serial Ports and Enable it
3. click Ok.
4. Now click Start
5. Select Devices from Top Menu
6. Select USB Devices
7. Select your Bluetooth Adapter
   that's all. now You can use your Laptop Bluetooth for VM.

Comment: Do not forget to look up your Bluetooth Adpter Hardware ID on the device manager in order to find the adapter in the USB Devices list of Virtual Box as it may not be identified (at least mine wasnt)

Comment: @Thomas How did you find your bluetooth adapter hardware id?

Comment: @HeberLZ: In Windows' Device Manager, double-click your Bluetooth adapter to open its Properties sheet. Select the Details tab, and then select Hardware IDs from the Properties ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the steps in RamRaj's answer, the VM's Bluetooth adapter requires an exclusive connection. No other devices may be paired on the laptop—otherwise the connection attempt will hang.

If the connection is successful, you won't be able to manage Bluetooth within the laptop (host) OS for the duration of the connection.