# to implement code which can receive continuous data from bluetooth health device and I'm getting runtime error on eclipse.

Tags: android

**This problem could be related to method "onDestroy()" which I've used in activity class.please help **

**BluetoothHDPActivity.java**

package com.example.bluetoothhdp;

```
   public class BluetoothHDPActivity extends Activity 

{

private static final String TAG = "BluetoothHealthActivity";
private static final int HEALTH_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE = 0x1007;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
private TextView mConnectIndicator;
private ImageView mDataIndicator;
private TextView mStatusMessage;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice[] mAllBondedDevices;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private int mDeviceIndex = 0;
private Resources mRes;
private Messenger mHealthService;
private boolean mHealthServiceBound;


private Handler mIncomingHandler = new Handler() 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        switch (msg.what) 
        {
            case BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG:mStatusMessage.setText(
                    String.format(mRes.getString(R.string.cancel),
                            msg.arg1));
                break;


            case BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_HEALTH_APP_UNREG:
                mStatusMessage.setText(
                        String.format(mRes.getString(R.string.copy),
                        msg.arg1));
                break;


            case BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_READ_DATA:
                mStatusMessage.setText(mRes.getString(R.string.copyUrl));
                mDataIndicator.setImageLevel(1);
                break;


            case BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE:
                mStatusMessage.setText(mRes.getString(R.string.cut));
                mDataIndicator.setImageLevel(0);
                break;

               case BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL:
                mStatusMessage.setText(
                        String.format(mRes.getString(R.string.defaultMsisdnAlphaTag),
                        msg.arg1));
                mConnectIndicator.setText("connected");
                break;

               case BluetoothHDPService.STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL:
                mStatusMessage.setText(
                              String.format(mRes.getString(R.string.defaultVoiceMailAlphaTag),
                        msg.arg1));
                mConnectIndicator.setText("Disconnected");
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};

private final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(mIncomingHandler);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) 
    {
       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this,"Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
    mConnectIndicator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addToDictionary);
    mStatusMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.background);

    mRes = getResources();
    mHealthServiceBound = false;


    Button registerAppButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    registerAppButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            sendMessage(BluetoothHDPService.MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP,
                    HEALTH_PROFILE_SOURCE_DATA_TYPE);
        }
    });


    Button unregisterAppButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    unregisterAppButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            sendMessage(BluetoothHDPService.MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP, 0);
        }
    });

    Button connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            mAllBondedDevices =
                    (BluetoothDevice[]) mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices().toArray(
                            new BluetoothDevice[0]);

            if (mAllBondedDevices.length > 0) 
            {
                int deviceCount = mAllBondedDevices.length;
                if (mDeviceIndex < deviceCount) mDevice = mAllBondedDevices[mDeviceIndex];
                else
                {
                    mDeviceIndex = 0;
                    mDevice = mAllBondedDevices[0];
                }
                String[] deviceNames = new String[deviceCount];
                int i = 0;
                for (BluetoothDevice device : mAllBondedDevices) 
                {
                    deviceNames[i++] = device.getName();
                }
                SelectDeviceDialogFragment deviceDialog =
                        SelectDeviceDialogFragment.newInstance(deviceNames, mDeviceIndex);
                deviceDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "deviceDialog");
            }
        }
    });


    Button disconnectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    disconnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            disconnectChannel();
        }
    });
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, initIntentFilter());
}


private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) 
    {
        mHealthServiceBound = true;
        Message msg = Message.obtain(null, BluetoothHDPService.MSG_REG_CLIENT);
        msg.replyTo = mMessenger;
        mHealthService = new Messenger(service);
        try {
            mHealthService.send(msg);
        } catch (RemoteException e) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to register client to service.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
    {
        mHealthService = null;
        mHealthServiceBound = false;
    }
};
@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHealthServiceBound) unbindService(mConnection);
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);


}


@Override
protected void onStart() 
{
    super.onStart();

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else 
    {
        initialize();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
        {
            initialize();
        } else {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
}

    public void setDevice(int position) 
{
    mDevice = this.mAllBondedDevices[position];
    mDeviceIndex = position;
}

private void connectChannel() 
{
    sendMessageWithDevice(BluetoothHDPService.MSG_CONNECT_CHANNEL);
}

private void disconnectChannel() 
{
    sendMessageWithDevice(BluetoothHDPService.MSG_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL);
}

private void initialize() 
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BluetoothHDPService.class);
    startService(intent);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}


private IntentFilter initIntentFilter() 
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    return filter;
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) 
        {
            if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR) ==
                BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) 
            {
                initialize();
            }
        }
    }
};


private void sendMessage(int what, int value) 
{
    if (mHealthService == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Health Service not connected.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        mHealthService.send(Message.obtain(null, what, value, 0));
    } catch (RemoteException e) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to reach service.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendMessageWithDevice(int what) 
{
    if (mHealthService == null) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Health Service not connected.");
        return;
    }

    try {
        mHealthService.send(Message.obtain(null, what, mDevice));
    } catch (RemoteException e) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to reach service.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static class SelectDeviceDialogFragment extends DialogFragment 
{

    public static SelectDeviceDialogFragment newInstance(String[] names, int position) 
    {
        SelectDeviceDialogFragment frag = new SelectDeviceDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray("names", names);
        args.putInt("position", position);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        String[] deviceNames = getArguments().getStringArray("names");
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position", -1);
        if (position == -1) position = 0;
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("select device")
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {
                            ((BluetoothHDPActivity) getActivity()).connectChannel();
                        }
                    })
                .setSingleChoiceItems(deviceNames, position,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                        {
                            ((BluetoothHDPActivity) getActivity()).setDevice(which);
                        }
                    }
                )
                .create();
    }
}}
```

**BluetoothHDPService.java**

package com.example.bluetoothhdp;

```
   public class BluetoothHDPService extends Service 

 {

private static final String TAG = "BluetoothHDPService";

public static final int RESULT_OK = 0;
public static final int RESULT_FAIL = -1;

public static final int STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG = 100;
public static final int STATUS_HEALTH_APP_UNREG = 101;
public static final int STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL = 102;
public static final int STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL = 103;
public static final int STATUS_READ_DATA = 104;
public static final int STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE = 105;
public static final int MSG_REG_CLIENT = 200;
public static final int MSG_UNREG_CLIENT = 201;
public static final int MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP = 300;
public static final int MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP = 301;
public static final int MSG_CONNECT_CHANNEL = 400;
public static final int MSG_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL = 401;

private BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration mHealthAppConfig;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothHealth mBluetoothHealth;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private int mChannelId;
private Messenger mClient;
private class IncomingHandler extends Handler 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        switch (msg.what) 
        {

            case MSG_REG_CLIENT:
                Log.d(TAG, "Activity client registered");
                mClient = msg.replyTo;
                break;

            case MSG_UNREG_CLIENT:
                mClient = null;
                break;

            case MSG_REG_HEALTH_APP:
                registerApp(msg.arg1);
                break;

            case MSG_UNREG_HEALTH_APP:
                unregisterApp();
                break;

            case MSG_CONNECT_CHANNEL:
                mDevice = (BluetoothDevice) msg.obj;
                connectChannel();
                break;

            case MSG_DISCONNECT_CHANNEL:
                mDevice = (BluetoothDevice) msg.obj;
                disconnectChannel();
                break;
            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

final Messenger mMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler());

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
    {
        stopSelf();
        return;
    }
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(this, mBluetoothServiceListener,
            BluetoothProfile.HEALTH)) {
       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(this, "HDP is not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.show();
        stopSelf();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    Log.d(TAG, "BluetoothHDPService is running.");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    return mMessenger.getBinder();
};


private void registerApp(int dataType) 
{
    mBluetoothHealth.registerSinkAppConfiguration(TAG, dataType, mHealthCallback);
}


private void unregisterApp() 
{
    mBluetoothHealth.unregisterAppConfiguration(mHealthAppConfig);
}


private void connectChannel() 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "connectChannel()");
    mBluetoothHealth.connectChannelToSource(mDevice, mHealthAppConfig);
}


private void disconnectChannel() 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "disconnectChannel()");
    mBluetoothHealth.disconnectChannel(mDevice, mHealthAppConfig, mChannelId);
}


private final BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mBluetoothServiceListener =
        new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() 
{
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) 
    {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEALTH)
        {
            mBluetoothHealth = (BluetoothHealth) proxy;
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected to profile: " + profile);
        }
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) 
    {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEALTH) 
        {
            mBluetoothHealth = null;
        }
    }
};

  private final BluetoothHealthCallback mHealthCallback = new BluetoothHealthCallback() 

    {


    public void onHealthAppConfigurationStatusChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,int status) 
    {
        if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_FAILURE) 
        {
            mHealthAppConfig = null;
            sendMessage(STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG, RESULT_FAIL);
        } else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS) 
        {
            mHealthAppConfig = config;
            sendMessage(STATUS_HEALTH_APP_REG, RESULT_OK);
        } else if (status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_FAILURE ||
                status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS) 
        {
            sendMessage(STATUS_HEALTH_APP_UNREG,
                    status == BluetoothHealth.APP_CONFIG_UNREGISTRATION_SUCCESS ?
                    RESULT_OK : RESULT_FAIL);
        }
    }

    public void onHealthChannelStateChange(BluetoothHealthAppConfiguration config,
            BluetoothDevice device, int prevState, int newState, ParcelFileDescriptor fd,
            int channelId) 
    {
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG))
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("prevState\t%d ----------> newState\t%d",
                    prevState, newState));
        if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED &&
                newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTED) 
        {
            if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) 
            {
                mChannelId = channelId;
                sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
                (new ReadThread(fd)).start();
            } else 
            {
                sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
            }
        } else if (prevState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_CONNECTING &&
                   newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) 
        {
            sendMessage(STATUS_CREATE_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
        } else if (newState == BluetoothHealth.STATE_CHANNEL_DISCONNECTED) 
        {
            if (config.equals(mHealthAppConfig)) 
            {
                sendMessage(STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL, RESULT_OK);
            } else 
            {
                sendMessage(STATUS_DESTROY_CHANNEL, RESULT_FAIL);
            }
        }
    }
};


private void sendMessage(int what, int value) 
{
    if (mClient == null) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "No clients registered.");
        return;
    }

    try 
    {
        mClient.send(Message.obtain(null, what, value, 0));
    } catch (RemoteException e) 
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class ReadThread extends Thread 
{
    private ParcelFileDescriptor mFd;

    public ReadThread(ParcelFileDescriptor fd) 
    {
        super();
        mFd = fd;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFd.getFileDescriptor());
        final byte data[] = new byte[8192];
        try {
            while(fis.read(data) > -1) 
            {
                sendMessage(STATUS_READ_DATA, 0);
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {}
        if (mFd != null) 
        {
            try {
                mFd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* Do nothing. */ }
        }
        sendMessage(STATUS_READ_DATA_DONE, 0);
    }
}}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.bluetooth.health"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.bluetoothhdp.BluetoothHDPActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category 
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service 
        android:name=".BluetoothHDPService" />
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.bluetoothhdp/com.example.bluetoothhdp.BluetoothHDPActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.bluetoothhdp.BluetoothHDPActivity$3@40ce3da8
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3451)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.bluetoothhdp.BluetoothHDPActivity$3@40ce3da8
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:657)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1339)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:445)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at com.example.bluetoothhdp.BluetoothHDPActivity.onDestroy(BluetoothHDPActivity.java:254)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5273)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1110)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3438)
         08-26 16:37:44.773: E/AndroidRuntime(802):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please show relevant code only? Also include what have you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: previously,error was "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo", then I debugged it by putting android:name="com.example.bluetoothhdp.BluetoothHDPActivity" in manifest and now its showing error which I've specified above.

Comment: You can still limit your code to relevant parts only.

Comment: Also,its showing "Unfortunately,App has stopped" on emulator.

Comment: can u tell me,in which file there is a problem?

Comment: now I've updated the LogCat

Comment: If I remove the "onDestroy()" from Activity class then it shows only error "E/BluetoothAdapter(948): Bluetooth binder is null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your manifest is a bit borked, especialy regarding the packages. You can try to modify it like the below, however you mention that your using the Emulator. The Emulator doesn't support bluetooth. So unless you have a physical phone that you test with, you'll need to run android as a virtual machine. There's a few other questions that deal with the virtual machine topic, e.g - [How to test Bluetooth Based Application on Androidx86 on top of VirtualBox with inbuilt laptop bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135442/how-to-test-bluetooth-based-application-on-androidx86-on-top-of-virtualbox-with)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.bluetoothhdp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity 
        android:name=".BluetoothHDPActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action 
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category 
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service 
        android:name=".BluetoothHDPService" />
  </application>
  </manifest>
```

Comment: Yes,I tried it on android phone also but its showing "Unfortunately,Appname has stopped".and with the changes given in above manifest it shows error in LogCat as "Unable to destroy activity"

Comment: now I've updated LogCat

Comment: If I remove the "onDestroy()" from Activity class then it shows only error "E/BluetoothAdapter(948): Bluetooth binder is null".