# How to find bluetooth mac address programmatically in Android api level 19

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat

I need to find bluetooth mac address in android. Below code

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress();
```

It works fine with api level 18 and below.

How to find the same with api level 19.?

"To get a BluetoothAdapter representing the local Bluetooth adapter, when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and below, call the static getDefaultAdapter() method; when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and higher, retrieve it through getSystemService(String) with BLUETOOTH_SERVICE" from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html

I am getting the following error:

```
bluetooth binder is null
```

with both

```
BluetoothManager ba=(BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
bmac=ba.getAdapter().getAddress();
```

and

```
bmac=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress();
```

on emulator and genymotion emulator for api level 19,kitkat

Help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33377982/7012517 for ur reference..!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Bluetooth is not supported by default neither on standard emulator nor on genymotion(There were rumours that Bluetooth will be supported by genymotion). You can enable bluetooth on your VirtualBox-based emulator [which is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135442/how-to-test-bluetooth-based-application-on-androidx86-on-top-of-virtualbox-with?rq=1) but I didn't try it.

Retrieving BluetoothAdapter from static method `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` is correct for all Platforms. BluetoothManager is available from API 18.