# Test bluetooth android app with virtual machines

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-bluetooth

I set up the virtual box / android environment  to test my bluetooth app as explained in this post ([How to test Bluetooth Based Application on Androidx86 on top of VirtualBox with inbuilt laptop bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135442/how-to-test-bluetooth-based-application-on-androidx86-on-top-of-virtualbox-with))

I am able to lauch the app on the VM from eclipse.
However, when my app tries to activate the virtual device bluetooth it is stuck on a "turning on bluetooth..." message

One thing I am not sure to get is if it's possible to test my app without an actual bluetooth hardware device. Cause I do not have any bluetooth dongle or bluetooth adapter on my PC.

So my question is basically: Is it possible to emulate the bluetooth between 2 VM for instance?

EDIT: So after investigating I was explained that no it is not possible to emulate bluetooth between virtual machine without actual physical bluetooth device.

So I got a bluetooth dongle.
I have sucessfully installed it to my PC.
In virtual box I add a filter in settings - USB and I am able to see the bluetooth USB device.

I start the virtual machine.
But when I go to android (4.3) settings - to activate bluetooth I see a "turning on bluetooth" message for few seconds then it goes back to "To see devices, turn Bluetooth on".

And I cannot find the reason why even after checking internet.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thx
Fabien